# Getting eloquent chaining to replicate join from mysql in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using a database mysql with a project table, an activity table and a user table.

A project has many activities and an activity is assigned to one person so I have the following links in my models:

```
Project model:

public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Activity::class, 'project_id');
    }
```

Then I have

```
Activity model:

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

I would like to get for a project, the list of users on it.

I can do

```
$project = App\Project::find(1);
$activities = $project->activities;
```

And this works, I get all the activities on this project.

I can do

```
$activity = App\Activity::find(43113);
$name = $activity->user->name;
```

But how can I get all the users name on a project?

I tried linking this but it is not working, it tells me I have a bad exception.
For example, this below doesn't work and generates an error:

```
$names = $project->activities->user;
or
$names = $project->activities->with('users');
```

I am on Laravel 7.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with` as below.

```
$project = App\Project::with('activities.user')->where('id',1)->first();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($project);
exit;
```

By using project you can get activities and per activities you've user.

Comment: ok, I see. I now get array of activities and collection of user. This is great. How can I get the list of users then? as I tried $names = $project->pluck('name'); after that but it doesn't find name in the table projects.

Comment: So, you want the user name which is associated with particular that project?

Comment: In fact, when I do this: $names = $project->activities->pluck('user.name'); I get all the names of the users who are on this project. The problem is that I get it many times and I cannot do a group by for example. This is because on a project there are many different activities and a user can work on several activities. I could have 5 activities for user A and 5 for user B. The command will give me 5 times A and 5 times B. I would need to get only one time A and one time B.

Comment: Ok, I found out in the documentation: $project->activities->unique('name')->pluck('user.name');